# Submit multi form in 1 click

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a homework require me to make a page where i need to submit Course and Student information.Requirement is i need a button that will generate a form to fill in Student information every time users click it.Users can generate as many as they want .After that user can click submit to submit everything on that page to Controller .The problem is i don't know how i can submit multi Student form to Controller.I try to use script to submit all the form but i think it not working.Please show me how

this is my jsp page now

```
<body>
    <form id="form" name="form" >
        <label for="fname">Course Name:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" ><br>
        <label for="lname">Course ID:</label><br>
        <input type="text" id="cid" name="cid" ><br><br>
    </form>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Add Student</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="submit()" id="submit">Save</button>
    <script>
        var x = 0;
        function myFunction() {
            x++;
            var br = document.createElement("br");
            var form = document.createElement("form");
            form.id = "form" + x;
            var FN = document.createElement("input");
            form.innerHTML = "Student" + x + "<br>";
            FN.type = "text";
            FN.name = "FullName" + x;
            FN.placeholder = "Name";
            var ID = document.createElement("input");
            ID.type = "text";
            ID.name = "id" + x;
            ID.placeholder = "Student ID";
            form.appendChild(FN);
            form.appendChild(br.cloneNode());
            form.appendChild(ID);
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(form);
        }
        function submit() {
            for (var i = 0; i < x; i++) {
                document.getElementById("form" + i).submit();
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: I have never use jsp but I did AJAX. In order to send multiple forms, you only need to send one after the other by two POST requests. Note that you have i= 0; i<0;++ in your for loop

Comment: change your for loop like this `for (var i = 1; i <= x; i++) {` and see if that works .currently you are intializing value of `i=0` but there is no form with id `form0` you start from `form1`.